# Access scope from a scope-isolated directive

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I am trying to call a scope function from inside a scope isolated directive,
here is my code :

```
angular.module('directive', [])
.directive('dirz', function() {
  return {
    restrict:'E',
    link: function(scope, elm, attrs, ctrl) {
    },
    controller: function() {
    }    
  };
})
.directive('dir1', function() {
  return {
    require: 'dirz', 
    scope:{},
    link: function(scope, elm, attrs, ctrl) {  
    }
  };
}) 
.directive('dir2', function() {
  return {
    restrict:'E',
    link: function(scope, elm, attrs, ctrl) {
      // this function is never called bacause of isolated scope ?
      scope.click = function(){
        console.log("somebody clicked me!!");
      }
    }
  }; 
});
```

and my html

```
<dirz dir1>
  <!-- I want to call click scope function in dir2 -->
  <button ng-click="click()">click</button>
</dirz>

<dir2></dir2>
```

this is a [plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/usVKzLO1RYyKYoJXDk1F?p=preview)

Am I doing it right, or is this an angular antipattern ?

Comment: Those scopes are not isolated. But they are not parent-child scopes, that's why you can do it the way you do.

Comment: Other than there is no scope hierarchy, one of the reason for isolated scope to exist is that they are isolated from other scope. Why do you want to break the isolation?

Comment: Actually, your code are working as you expect in the latest version of angular 1.2.21. http://plnkr.co/edit/x1Q7GJEhFunVrq3BFHHa?p=preview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `click()` handler is not accessible within `dir1`'s isolated scope.

To trigger both clicks, move the button HTML to your directive's template (the template will be linked against the isolated scope) and then call $broadcast to send a message to `dir2`.  This might be your best option since the DIVs are siblings to eachother rather than in a parent/child relationship.

```
.directive('dir1', function() {
  return {
    require: 'dirz', 
    template: '<button ng-click="click()">click</button>',
    controller: function($scope, $rootScope) { 
         $scope.click = function() {
             console.log('somebody clicked me');
             $rootScope.$broadcast('click');
         }
    },
    scope:{},
    link: function(scope, elm, attrs, ctrl) {  
    }
  };
}) 
.directive('dir2', function() {
  return {
    restrict:'E',
    link: function(scope, elm, attrs, ctrl) {
      // this function is never called bacause of isolated scope ?
      scope.$on('click', function() {
           console.log('received click message');
      });
    }
  }; 
});
```

HTML

```
<dirz dir1>
</dirz>

<dir2>
</dir2>
```